# Update jQuery DataTable using Entity Framework Core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, datatables, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have a .NET Core app with Razor Pages and Entity Framework 5.0.  I am using jQuery's DataTable (1.10.21) to display data from the database, it is in a partial page.

I have an Add button that brings up a Bootstrap (4.3.1) modal for the user to enter data for a new object.  Upon success, the new object (Student) is persisted to the database using EF. The javascript displays a notification on the Index page and then tries to update the DataTable to hold the latest data.

The only ways I have been able to make the DataTable refresh have been:

1. Do a windows.location to reload the whole page
2. Have the jquery that is closing the modal call the OnGet for the partial page that holds the DataTable.  It will then replace the div with the updated div.  Because the DOM has been changed, I have to re-instantiate the DataTable.

#2 almost gets me where I need to be - it prevents reloading the entire page but since I have to re-instantiate the DataTable, the filter/sort state gets cleared.

I know DataTable has an add() to add a new row but every example uses JSON, not EF objects.  I haven't attempted to delete or edit a row yet but I will need to do those as well and I will have the same problem - not being able to update the DataTable without losing its state.

I added the code for _StudentModalPartial.cshtml as requested by @Rena. I am adding some very distinct questions around other things I have tried.

1. Instead of replacing the `<div>` with the DataTable in the site.js after the isValid check, I can return a built `<tr>` and add it to the DataTable. I have seen this as a possible solution but have not tried to implement it because it is not a good solution. It would prevent re-instantiating the DataTable and losing the state, however, it is cumbersome to build the `<tr>` and include all of the columns, rendered buttons, and data.  My real application is much more complicated than this Student example and maintenance would be difficult.  In addition, it doesn't solve the problem for Delete and Edit.
2. So far, I have been able to use the EF objects in the HTML/DataTable without issue. If I can't use HTML as the data source when trying to use the row.add(), row.remove() functions (which seems to be the case),
   then what is the best approach when dealing with EF objects?  I read one tutorial that included a lot of logic to convert the EF object to JSON just to use the table.  Seems there should be a cleaner way.

Here is the Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model SuzRazorApp.Pages.Students.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Students";
}

<h2>Students</h2>

<div class="container-fluid pt-3 pb-3">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-url="@Url.Page("Index", "StudentModalPartial" )">
        Add <i class="fas fa-plus fa-sm"></i>
    </button>
</div>

<!-- Modal placeholder -->
<div id="modal-placeholder"></div>

<!-- Students table -->
<partial name="_StudentsTablePartial" model="Model.Students" />

@section Scripts
{
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#example').DataTable({
            stateSave: true,
            stateDuration: -1,
            columnDefs: [
                { orderable: false, targets: 3 },
                { searchable: false, targets: [2, 3] }
            ]
        });
    });

    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })

</script>
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
namespace SuzRazorApp.Pages.Students
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SchoolContextContext _context;
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public IndexModel(SchoolContextContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _context = context;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public IList<Student> Students { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Students = await _context.Students.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetStudentsTablePartial()
        {
            Students = await _context.Students.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

            return Partial("_StudentsTablePartial", Students);
        }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetStudentModalPartial()
        {
            // This handler returns _StudentModalPartial with empty Student object
            return Partial("_StudentModalPartial", new Student { });
        }

        // Save added data
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostStudentModalPartialAsync(Student model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)  // if errors on page, don't save
            {
                _context.Students.Add(model);

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            //  Show the modal again but with the user's entries and the errors (errors handled via validation/annotation)
            return Partial("_StudentModalPartial", model);
        }
    }
}
```

Partial Page for DataTable (_StudentTablePartial.cshtml)

```
@model IList<Models.Student>

<div id="divTable" class="container-fluid" data-url="@Url.Page("Index", "StudentsTablePartial")">
    <table id="example" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Last Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    First Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Enrollment Date
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
                    </td>

                    <td style="white-space:nowrap">
                        <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"> <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"></i> </a>
                        <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id"> <i class="far fa-trash-alt" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"></i> </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

site.js method called after Save from modal

```
//  Button brings up modal using a place holder in the calling page and adds a button click function for the Save button
$(function () {
    var placeholderElement = $('#modal-placeholder');

    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            placeholderElement.html(data);
            placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        });
    });

    placeholderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {
        // prevent default button click actions
        event.preventDefault();

        // grab form data and send it
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var dataToSend = form.serialize();

        // Grab URL from form action attribute and post form:
        $.post(actionUrl, dataToSend).done(function (data) {
            // data is the rendered _ContactModalPartial
            var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);
            // replace modal contents with new form
            placeholderElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);

            // close modal if data is valid
            var isValid = newBody.find('[name="IsValid"]').val() === 'True';
            if (isValid) {
                $('#notificationsPlaceholder').find("p").text('Successfully saved data!');
                $('#notificationsPlaceholder').show();

                var divTableElement = $('#divTable');
                var divTableUrl = divTableElement.data('url');
                $.get(divTableUrl).done(function (data) {  // data = view rendered with model returned from get method
                    //console.log(typeof data); // string
                    //console.log(data); // HTML content of the jQuery.ajax page
                    divTableElement.html(data);   // replace the divTableElement with the updated data

                    $('#example').DataTable();  // After the data is placed in the DOM, need to initialize DataTables plugin again
                });

                placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

_StudentModalPartial.cshtml

```
@model SuzRazorApp.Models.Student

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="add-student" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addStudentLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addStudentLabel">Add Student</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-page-handler="StudentModalPartial">
                    <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="FirstMidName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="FirstMidName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FirstMidName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="EnrollmentDate"></label>
                        <input asp-for="EnrollmentDate" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="EnrollmentDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @sldorman, please remember to share your `_StudentModalPartial`.

Comment: Thank you @Rena for the feedback, I added the _StudentModalPartial.cshtml and added context, more specific questions.

Comment: Hi @sldorman, I have tested your whole code and it could update the datatable successfully, so what is your requirement?

Comment: Hi @Rena, it does update the datatable and it does it without reloading the whole page but it is replacing the datatable. Since the DOM has changed, I have re-instantiate the datatable in the javascript - $('#example').DataTable();  Once I do that, any selections the user may have made - like filtering or sorting - are lost.  I'm trying to retain the state but add the new row.  I also want to retain the state when deleting and editing.  I put more detail in my post the other day but I see that some characters didn't come through.  I will fix that.